# How to upload (FTP) images with a certain group?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, upload, ftp

I've configured a IP Camera that upload images in a Ubuntu Server.

In Ubuntu server is runnig Apache http server and vsftpd (Very Simpe FTP Daemon).

I have to catch the images from a wep application,

- how I have to configure the permissions ? (without security problems)

I thought that I can set the group of uploaded images to www-data,

- can this works in my case ?
- how can I set configure the FTP server (vsftpd) to set the images uploaded to www-data ?

thank you,
Alessandro

Comment: This is hard to answer, as we don't know what user your web application runs as. Find that out first, e.g. by creating a file from the web application and looking what owner it has.

Comment: And this seems to be a software configuration question, so it doesn't really belong on SO, you might have more luck on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set change the group of the director(y|ies) it gets uploaded to to www-data and set the set-gid (chmod g+s) bit on the director(y|ies), this should force newly created files/directories to get the www-data group, instead of the primary group of the process that creates it.